# Delete item from database ListView

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-listview

I have encountered a problem in my Android application.  I can only delete an item in my ListView, but not from my database.  I need some help here.  I need to delete it from my database.  Here is my code:

```
final ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, strlist2);
    listContent.setAdapter(adapter);
    listContent.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            listContent.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);
            listContent.setSelector(android.R.color.holo_blue_light);
            listContent.setItemsCanFocus(false);
            final int positionToRemove = position;
            String string = String.valueOf(id);
            dbAdapter.remove(string);
            dbAdapter.delete123456(string);
            adapter.remove(adapter.getItem(positionToRemove));
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });
```

Here is my dbAdapter.remove and my dbAdapter.delete123456 code:

```
    public boolean delete123456(String rowId) {
/*      this is what your database delete method should look like
    this method deletes by id, the first column in your database*/
    return mDb.delete(FTS_VIRTUAL_TABLE, KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowId, null) > 0;
}
public void remove(String id){
    mDb.delete(FTS_VIRTUAL_TABLE, KEY_ROWID +"=?", new String [] { id });
}
```

I need help here.  I have been banging my head on the wall for the whole day now.  Any help regarding this problem would be appreciated.

Comment: Please, you have asked this question 4 times in this forum!!!!

Comment: I'm sorry, no one has answered me and this is a different question.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way.

```
listContent.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            listContent.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);
            listContent.setSelector(android.R.color.holo_blue_light);
            listContent.setItemsCanFocus(false);
            String[] delete = names2.get(position);
            String idString = delete[0];
            long idLong = Long.valueOf(idString);
            Log.d("Deleting...", idLong + "");
            dm.delete(idLong);        // dm is your Datamanipulator class object
            names2.remove(position);
            stg1=new String[names2.size()];
            int x=0;
            String stg;

            for (String[] dag : names2) {
                stg = dag[1]+" - "+dag[2]+ " - "+dag[3]+" - "+dag[4];
                stg1[x]=stg;
                x++;
            }
           adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });
```

Here **names2** is your String list array so replace it name with your's array name.

Comment: Where exactly do I put this `onListItemClick`?

Comment: The thing is that I don't have a list array, I only have an array.  I only have an adapter.  I have strlist, but that is a string.

Comment: `List<String[]> names2 = null;` if it is like this then Okay.

Comment: This causes a nullpointerexception because the list is null.

Comment: Try inserting some value first then check whether it is working with data or not if yes then just we need to pass if condition,

Comment: @Rohodude, whether it worked or not

Comment: Check my updated answer now it will not give null pointer exception.